# Character pose resetting in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, pose-mode

I posed my character in pose mode ,but once I go into edit mode the entire pose resets. Is there any way to prevent this?

[image: In pose mode]

[image: In edit mode]

Comment: This is the way rigs are intended to work: edit mode pose is the rest pose. So, what are you aiming at? Maybe having your posed character to be in rest pose pointing the gun as in the first picture?

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm aiming at. Do you know how I can do that?

Answer (score 1):

Select the gun, press Alt P (Clear parent and keep transformation).

Select the mesh, go to its armature modifier and apply it.
If the character has different pieces repeat for all objects.

Select the armature and press Ctrl A Apply pose as rest pose.

Add to the mesh (or meshes) an armature modifier pointing at the rig.

Re-establish the parentship between Gun and hand (which I can't know how it has been setup).

Every weight will stay intact.

Comment: It works! Thanks :)

Comment: If useful please check the answer as accepted.